# Проблема с фиксированным элементом

Tags: html, css

```
    table {
    *border-collapse: collapse; /* Для IE7 и старше */
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;    
}

#FM {
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
}

.bordered {
    position: absolute;
    border: solid #ccc 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc; 
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;    
}

/*.bordered #t_hover:hover {
    background: #fff;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;     
} */

.bordered td{
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;    
    max-width: 1000px;
}

 .bordered th {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;    
}

.bordered th {
    background-color: #777;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#777), to(#555));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #777, #555);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #777, #555);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #777, #555);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #777, #555);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #777, #555);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.8) inset; 
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.8) inset;  
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.8) inset;        
    border-top: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5); 
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.bordered td:first-child, .bordered th:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

.bordered th:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
}

.bordered th:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
    border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
}

.bordered tr:last-child td:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 6px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 6px;
}

.bordered tr:last-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 6px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 6px 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 6px 0;
}
.bordered img {
    margin: 5px 5px 5px;
    //border: 2px solid #777;
}

    <table class="bordered">
    <thead id="FM">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>        
        <th>Название</th>
        <th>Раздают</th>
        <th>Качают</th>
        <th>Размер</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    .....
    .....
```

Немогу понять, как сделать фиксированным заголовок таблицы. В данном примере получается вот такое http://i073.radikal.ru/1112/92/698f9d45945f.pngТ.е. как бы не по всей ширене экрана, нужно, чтобы было вот так 
http://s41.radikal.ru/i093/1112/38/383951c04bb2.jpg только немогу понять как сделать , так, чтобы он был фиксированным и в тоже время сохранял свои пропорции

Comment: а Вы разве не видите, что там, видимо, заданы размеры всей таблицы и каждого столбца?

Comment: я не очень разбираюсь в CSS, обновил первый пост

Comment: просмотрел обновления. ситуация в том, что размеры (свойство `width`) задаётся только в одном месте - для всей таблицы на 100% ширины страницы. у Вас 5 столбцов, т.е. автоматически ширина для них устанавливается по 20% от общей ширины таблицы.
На мой взгляд, можно решить так: задать размеры самой страницы, а затем задать ширину для каждого столбца, например для первого - 5%, для второго - 65%, для третьего и четвёртого - по 15%.....может, поможет....(и про высоту не забудьте))

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать )